# Selecting multiple files using VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript, jscript, hta, filesystemobject

I'm using the following script in Windows 7/10 to open a file dialog and allow the user to select a file. It's not allowing me to select multiple files even with the multiple attribute added. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), I should be able to use the multiple attribute with `<input type="file">` to select multiple files.

```
Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set oExec = wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE name=file multiple><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""") 
sFileSelected = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
WScript.Echo sFileSelected
```

Comment: Try replacing with `id='files' name='files[]'` - are you not allowed to select multiple files or do you have issue showing values when you read results

Comment: I'd recall `multiple` attribute was not supported before IE10 or even IE11, in which document mode you run the app?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an HTA, add the following code inside the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"/>
```